# How to associate the last message with the 1-1 channel list in PUBNUB REACT?

Tags: reactjs, channel, pubnub

I have this requirement where i have to populate 1-1 channels on the left side . With the channels list I have to show the last sent message in the channel with each channel . How can I achieve this ?

I thought of a process where i would

1. Generate the list of joined channels
2. Fetch the last message of each channel by calling the history api
3. Then associate the last message with the meta data of the channel
4. Show it in the view

Is this the better approach or there are any other ways to do it better ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Actually, your question is quite good in my opinion. You are definitely on the right track as far as I can tell. Did you have any challenges with implementing the design you have laid out?

Comment: Actually, I am in the stage where I have to do POC and tell the client whether we can achieve all the features or not. What I have learned after implementing some steps is that it might get a little slower for the first time when loading the inbox if there are a lot of channels.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach sounds great, I followed similar steps when I put my chat demo together a few months ago: https://github.com/PubNubDevelopers/PubNub-Showcase/tree/main/web/chat.  I'll copy the relevant code here:

> Generate the list of joined channels

This returns all channel members, you could filter for only channels you are a member of.

```js
    pubnub.objects
          .getChannelMembers({
            channel: channel,
            sort: { updated: 'desc' },
            include: {
              UUIDFields: true
            },
            totalCount: true
          })
```

> Fetch the last message of each channel by calling the history API

```js
    //  Load channel history
            pubnub
              .fetchMessages({
                channels: [channelName],
                count: 20, //  Limit to 20 messages.  Design decision for this app, not a limitation of PubNUb
                includeUUID: true,
                includeMessageActions: true
              })
```

> Then associate the last message with the meta data of the channel

I associated the last read timetoken, but you could associate the last message in the same way

```js
    pubnub.objects.setMemberships({
      channels: [{ id: channel, custom: { lastReadTimetoken: timetoken } }],
      uuid: pubnub.getUserId()
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to my previous answer, there is now an alternative API from PubNub specifically for Chat: https://www.pubnub.com/docs/chat/chat-sdk/overview

> Generate the list of joined channels

```js
const channels = await chat.getChannels()
```

> Fetch the last message of each channel by calling the history API

```js
// reference the "channel" object
const channel = await chat.getChannel("support")
// invoke the "getHistory()" method on the "channel" object
await channel.getHistory(
    {
        startTimetoken: "15343325214676133",
        count: 10
    }
)
```